# "Sanitizing" arbitrary SQL using inner SELECT queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a system where I'd like people to do arbitrary select queries on a number of databases with a number of tables.

Can I "sanitize" queries by simply embedding them in a subquery, i.e. `SELECT * FROM ( $USER_SELECT_QUERY )` ?

This would allow users to do any kind SELECT query, but would produce syntax errors on any `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `EXEC` etc. query. Can you come up with any kind of query that would modify/insert/delete data, or reveal other un-intended details about the host system, such as directory lists or anything else?

Assumptions:

- A user may access all data in all attached databases.
- Appropriate configuration/monitoring of query time and resource usage are in place to mitigate (D)DOS attacks.
- (Databases are readonly sqlite files in my case)

Please also note that I'm fully aware of the general dangers of allowing users to execute arbitrary SQL, so I'd like to emphasize that I'm very specifically asking about limitations to using select-subqueries for sanitizing query.

Comment: Why not set users to read only access on the database as a security level? This seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: My reasoning was to limit the scope of statements that are allowed. `ATTACH` could be a problem in sqlite, and other "weird" statements as `EXPLAIN` and `VACUUM` are somewhat out of scope of what users should be allowed to do.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent most of these statements, use an [authorization callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html).

You can also use [sqlite3_stmt_readonly()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt_readonly.html) to prevent any writes.

You should ensure that you do not have any dangerous user-defined functions or virtual tables, and that functions like [load_extension()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension) or [fts3_tokenizer()](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_8_1) are disabled.